# How to move the object (two-dimensional) based on its angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I'm studying some details in **unity** where I ended up falling into a dead end. First of all I would like to know, is there probably a functionality for that, but how increasing speed to an object based on the angle it is looking at. Please could you demonstrate with *examples* because so far my ideas are dull. I tried to do this functionality using math (probably a bad idea), because I was curious to know how such a situation worked in mathematical practice, developed some theories about it:

First I thought, at the ***90 degree*** angle, in one move, only the *Y axis* increases, so the *X axis* stays at 0. So to find out the exact variation of X and Y for a given angle, all you have to do is to find the angle secant and increment it, or is in another point? Probably my thinking is wrong, I'm "new" with trigonometry, but I would love to know what I was wrong, and if I was wrong, what is right to think.

If I said a lot of things wrong, let me know, because I know I need to study more :)

Below is the code of the function I created, which initially just made my character rotate on the Y axis, so just increment or decrement the speed value. So I added a method to generate a random angle based on the point of view that the object is looking at, so I just used different quadrants.

```
void invertMove()
{
    if(!inverse)
    {
        float tempRot = Random.Range(180f, 360f);
        zombieSpeed = -0.01f;
        zombieBody.SetRotation(tempRot);
        inverse = true;
    }
    else
    {
        float tempRot = Random.Range(0f, 180f);
        zombieSpeed = 0.01f;
        zombieBody.SetRotation(tempRot);
        inverse = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what `SetRotation` is but If you want to generate a random angle in degrees then get the x/y coordinates you get from rotating a rightward unit vector counterclockwise by that angle, then you can do `float randomAngle = Random.Range(0f, 360f);`
`Vector2 coords = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(randomAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), Mathf.Sin(randomAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad));`

Comment: @Ruzihm [`SetRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.SetRotation.html) seems to be from `Rigidbody2D` ;)

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what `zombieSpeed` does but assuming you are talking about [`Rigidbody2D.SetRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.SetRotation.html) here you probably wanted to assign a new `velocity`.

The `velocity` is in **global space**. You can't use e.g. `transform.right` as new direction since the `transform` isn't updated yet .. only the `zombieBody` is .. but you can use [`Rigidbody2D.GetRelativeVector`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.GetRelativeVector.html)  in order to set the new local direction after rotating

> Get a **global space vector** given the vector `relativeVector` in `rigidBody` **local space**.

```
// or Vector2.up depending on your setup
zombieBody.velocity = zombieBody.GetRelativeVector(Vector2.right * 0.01f);
```

---

So depending on your needs you wouldn't differ between a positive and negative speed but rather stay at `0.01f` and use

- For creating a new completely random direaction

  ```
  void newRandomDirection()
      float newRot = Random.Range(0f, 360f);
      zombieBody.SetRotation(newRot);
      zombieBody.velocity = zombieBody.GetRelativeVector(Vector2.right * 0.01f);
  }
  ```
- For actually inverting the direction you could simply do

  ```
  void invertMove()
  {
      var newRot = zombieBody.rotation + 180f;
      // optionally you can always fix it to a value 0-360 but that's not really required
      //if(newRot > 360f)
      //{
      //    newRot -= 360f;
      //}
      zombieBody.SetRotation(newRot);
      zombieBody.velocity = zombieBody.GetRelativeVector(Vector2.right * 0.01f);
  }
  ```
- Or if what you want is getting a new random direction somewhere between -90(== +270) to 90 degrees to the current direction I would rather use

  ```
  void invertMoveHemiSphere()
  {
      var newRot = zombieBody.rotation + Random.Range(90f, 270f);
      // optionally you can always fix it to a value 0-360 but that's not really required
      //if(newRot < 0f)
      //{
      //    newRot += 360f;
      //} 
      //else if(newRot > 360f)
      //{
      //    newRot -= 360f;
      //}
      zombieBody.SetRotation(newRot);
      zombieBody.velocity = zombieBody.GetRelativeVector(Vector2.right * 0.01f);
  }
  ```
- or sticking to what you did so far

  ```
  void invertMove()
  {
      inverse = !inverse;

      float newRot = inverse? Random.Range(0f, 180f) : Random.Range(180f, 360f);
      zombieBody.SetRotation(newRot);
      zombieBody.velocity = zombieBody.GetRelativeVector(Vector2.right * 0.01f);   
  }
  ```